# Pydantic dynamic model creation with json description attribute

Tags: python, pydantic

When pydantic model is created using class definition, the "description" attribute can be added to the JSON schema by adding a class docstring:

```py
class account_kind(str, Enum):
    """Account kind enum."""
    regular = "r"
    premium = "p"
```

yields

```json
"account_kind": {
  "title": "account_kind",
  "description": "Account kind enum.",
  "enum": ["r", "p"],
  "type": "string"
}
```

How do I add "description" when I use dynamic model creation via *create_model*?

```py
company = create_model("company", **company_attributes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the most straightforward option is to add the docstring explicitly:

```py
company = create_model("company", **company_attributes)
company.__doc__ = "Company description."
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to set the description for the individual attributes, like it would have been done statically with: `regular = pydantic.Field("r", description="some desc"`?

Comment: See answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/74317070