# How to control field label case generated by Pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have the following *pydantic* model:

```py
import pydantic

class Creator(pydantic.BaseModel):
    firstName: str = None
    lastName: str = None
    middle_name: str = None
```

and the output of `print(Creator.schema_json(indent=2))` is

```json
{
  "title": "Creator",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "title": "Firstname",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "title": "Lastname",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "middle_name": {
      "title": "Middle Name",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Field labels (the "title" attribute in field specs, not the main title) have the title case. However, only underscore separated attributes are split into components. How can I control the algorithm of generation of the "title" attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/) answering your question?

```py
import pydantic

class SampleModel(pydantic.BaseModel):
    firstName: str = pydantic.Field(
        None,
        title='First Name',
        description='the first name'
    )
    middle_name: str = pydantic.Field(
        None,
        title='Middle Name',
        description='the middle name' 
    )

print(SampleModel.schema_json(indent=2))
```

```json
{
  "title": "SampleModel",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "title": "First Name",
      "description": "the first name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "middle_name": {
      "title": "Middle Name",
      "description": "the middle name",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you want generate `title` automatically, you may use [sub-class `Config`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#schema-customization):

```py
import pydantic

class SampleModel(pydantic.BaseModel):

    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema, model):
            for name, prop in schema.get('properties', {}).items():
                prop['title'] = name.upper()

    firstName: str = None
    middle_name: str = None

print(SampleModel.schema_json(indent=2))
```

```json
{
  "title": "SampleModel",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "title": "FIRSTNAME",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "middle_name": {
      "title": "MIDDLE_NAME",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. The first one is not acceptable. The second one with some adjustments does work for me. It is kind of verbose, but anyways.