# Pydantic add descriptions to dynamic model

Tags: python, pydantic

I was wondering if there is a way to assign `description` when creating a model dynamically. The static equivalent would be

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, create_model

class MainModel(BaseModel):
    value1: int = Field(-1, description="desc1")
    value2: int = Field(-2, description="desc2")

print(MainModel.schema_json(indent=2))
```

Dynamically, what I have so far is

```py
from pydantic import create_model

attrs = {"value1": -1, "value2": -2}
m = create_model("MainModel", **attrs)
print(m.schema_json(indent=2))
```

Is there a way to include the `description` field for the individual attributes?

---

Related post: [Pydantic dynamic model creation with json description attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74234979/pydantic-dynamic-model-creation-with-json-description-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but if does give a similar JSON to what your static equivalent does. Look into `FieldInfo`.

```
from pydantic import create_model
from pydantic.fields import FieldInfo


attrs = {
    "value1": (int, FieldInfo(-1, description="desc1")),
    "value2": (int, FieldInfo(-2, description="desc2")),
}
m = create_model("MainModel", **attrs)

print(m.schema_json(indent=2))
```

That gives the following JSON

```
{
  "title": "MainModel",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "value1": {
      "title": "Value1",
      "description": "desc1",
      "default": -1,
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "value2": {
      "title": "Value2",
      "description": "desc2",
      "default": -2,
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

Actually, this also seems to give the same output, I do not use this library much so I am not sure how they differ.

```
attrs = {
    "value1": Field(-1, description="desc1"),
    "value2": Field(-2, description="desc2"),
}
```